# jQuery smooth scroll when showing element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a simple jQuery scroll function that scrolls to a div when an element is clicked.

The problem I am having is that because the function is both displaying an element and then scrolling to it, the scroll is not smooth because at the same time as the div is being shown, the scrolling begins

Is there any way I can either delay the animation so that the #wrapper div can load, and then the animation can scroll? Or something along those lines so that the scroll is smooth

Here is the jQuery function:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.divOne').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').show();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.divTwo').offset().top}, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Comment: And what is loading in the `#wrapper` div, from the posted code it should show up immediately, so you have to explain to us why it's not.

Comment: It is just displaying the #wrapper div which has img elements and p elements, but because it is displaying at the same time as the scroll starts, the scroll isn't smooth

Comment: Maybe you should preload the images then

Comment: Is there not a way i can just delay the scroll for a little bit, so the div can be displayed? The #wrapper div has already loaded in the DOM, but it just has the css display:none property

Comment: If it's already loaded, it should show up immediately, there should be almost no delay at all.

Comment: Try something like -> https://jsfiddle.net/xqga6gg1/

Comment: Thanks that pretty much works! if you make it an answer i can accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can preload the images, so they are already loaded when someone clicks, and the `#wrapper` element with it's images will be shown instantly

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
   $('#wrapper img').each(function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = this.src;
   });

  $('.divOne').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').show();
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: $('.divTwo').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `delay()` to the animation.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('.divOne').click(function() {
    $('#wrapper').show();
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.divTwo').offset().top}, 'slow').delay(2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.fadeIn()` instead of `.show()` with a callback.  See below:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.divOne').click(function(event) {
            $('#wrapper').fadeIn(150, function() {
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: $('.divTwo').offset().top}, 'slow');
            });
        });

   });
```